# Python package Sympy: Why the conjugate of a matrix leads to an abstract tensor product

Tags: python, sympy

If I do

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.quantum import TensorProduct
m = Matrix([[0,1],[0,0]])
TensorProduct(m,m)
```

I get

```
Matrix([
[0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

which is the correct result.
However, if I try

```
TensorProduct(conjugate(m),m)
```

I get

```
Matrix([
[0, 1],
[0, 0]])xMatrix([
[0, 1],
[0, 0]])
```

why does the conjugate function "force" the TensorProduct function to considerate conjugate(m) in an abstract way? Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: I'm not really a sympy user but perhaps they might be working on different fields (e.g. real vs complex). Check their underlying types. EDIT: `m` is a `sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix` and `conjugate(m)` is `sympy.matrices.immutable.ImmutableDenseMatrix`. Whatever that means...

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I found a way to fix it by feeding the output of conjugate to the function Matrix, i.e. ```TensorProduct(Matrix(conjugate(m)),m)``` .
Maybe this is connected to what you suggested, because it "forces" ```conjugate(m)``` to be of the same type as ```m``` ?